# How to import trained machine learning model from AI Patform into cloud functions in python

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a trained machine learning model to predict one metric of my data in firestore.

I have inserted data into bigquery to train the model and ones it is trained I want to deploy it to make predictions and insert this predictions again in firestore.

I have been reading a lot how to do this and finally I have found a way to do it: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/serverless-machine-learning-with-python-and-firebase-cloud-functions/

I have a few questions of this guide:

1. In the 4th step of this guide he save the model in firebase_admin storage. Why in firebase_admin storage and not in a google cloud storage?

[image]

2. He deploy the model in Google cloud ML engine. Why he do that? what advantadges I have to deploy the model there instead of save the model in Google cloud storage and after that call it in cloud functions? or it is necessary to do this step?

[image]

3. Once he deploy this model in Google cloud ML engine I can call it in a cloud fuction in python to run the model whatever the trigger I choose?

[image]

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question to post on Stack Overflow.  It will be easier for others to answer your individual questions, and for others to search and find similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/working-with-cloud-storage), as well. In the tutorial he suggests a way of achieving something, but it is not the single absolute way.

2) You can also do what you have said, but the way from that tutorial is better, I would say. You have the advantage of exposing your model as an API endpoint. This way you will have less work to do in the Cloud Functions code which is good.

3) I am not sure if I understood this question. You should use a HTTP trigger since you are trying to hit an API endpoint.

Comment: 2) Could you explain me what advantages I have exposing a model as an API endpoint? why it makes me have less work to do in cloud functions?

3) I wanted to say that I will trigger this with a cloud scheduler, but my question was on how import the model, I can import the trained model from AI platform to make predictions into cloud functions?

Comment: Because training a model is an operation which costs a lot of memory and you would prefer your models already trained while being called by Cloud Functions. You do not want to train the model inside a Cloud Function. And for the second question , yes and here there it is exampled on how to do it + code example : https://cloud.google.com/solutions/building-a-serverless-ml-model